# ui-sref does not produce correct href with parameter

Tags: angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I'm trying to use ui-router to change state and pass a GUID parameter to my controller.  I have this working using Kendo (different syntax) so I know what I'm aiming for.  I cannot for the life of me figure out what the deal is.  I have searched far and wide and I believe that I have the correct syntax for the ui-sref.  Here it is:

```html
<a ui-sref="clientEdit({ clientId: '{{vm.clientModel.id}}' })">Edit Link</a>
```

Produces this output in the rendered view (notice missing id):

```html
<a ui-sref="clientEdit({ clientId: 'bfd50b6c-6542-48c5-adf7-8c1a21caf421' })" href="#/clientEdit/">Edit Link</a>
```

Here is my state:

```js
.state("clientEdit", {
  url: "/clientEdit/:clientId",
  templateUrl: "/CompanyDashboard/ClientsCrud",
  controller: "DashboardClientsCtl",
  controllerAs: "vm"
})
```

When I hardcode the ID into the ui-sref it works as expected and produces the correct href for the  tag.  Like this:

```html
<a ui-sref="clientEdit({clientId:'bfd50b6c-6542-48c5-adf7-8c1a21caf421'})">Hard code Edit Link</a>
```

The hard-coded ID tag produces this output in the rendered view (exactly as I would expect):

```html
<a ui-sref="clientEdit({clientId:'bfd50b6c-6542-48c5-adf7-8c1a21caf421'})" href="#/clientEdit/bfd50b6c-6542-48c5-adf7-8c1a21caf421">Hard code Edit Link</a>
```

So, my question is:  Am I missing something here?  I really believe this should work as I'm already doing this successfully using a Kendo template for a different route.

Just in case you care, here is the working kendo template code:

```js
template: "<a ui-sref='clientDetails({clientId:\"#=id#\"})'>#=customerNumber#</a>"
```

I have tried changing quotes to double as in the Kendo example, removing the quotes, removing the {{ }} from the Id expression.  No Joy.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here is to **NOT** wrap the param with `{{}}`

```
// instead of this
<a ui-sref="clientEdit({ clientId: '{{vm.clientModel.id}}' })">Edit Link</a>
// use this
<a ui-sref="clientEdit({ clientId: vm.clientModel.id})">Edit Link</a>
```

The content of a `vm.clientModel.id` is already a string, and will be correctly passed as string *(it is GUID for JS it is string)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Just tried this and it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I thought I had tried this yesterday before I posted the question, but I had not.  Here is the correct syntax:

```html
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ui-sref="clientEdit({ clientId: {{'vm.clientModel.id'}} })">Edit Client Test</a>
```

Notice that the single quotes are INSIDE the {{  }} and not on the outside.  Simple eh?

This HTML produces the correct HREF like this:

```html
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ui-sref="clientEdit({ clientId: vm.clientModel.id })" href="#/clientEdit/bfd50b6c-6542-48c5-adf7-8c1a21caf421">Edit Client Test</a>
```